# Can't create new posts in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Suddently the "publish" button has vanished, and there is the "send for review" button instead on new posts.
When clicking the "save draft" button I get "you are not allowed to..." message.
I enabled debugging on WordPress, and when I navigate to the new post page, I get:

```
WordPress database error: [Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'post_date_gmt' at row 1]
```

`INSERT INTO 'wp_posts' ('post_author','post_date','post_date_gmt','post_content','post_content_filtered','post_title','post_excerpt','post_status','post_type','comment_status','ping_status','post_password','post_name','to_ping','pinged','post_modified','post_modified_gmt','post_parent','menu_order','guid')
 VALUES 
(1,'2019-07-14 12:53:19','0000-00-00 00:00:00','','','autodraft','','auto-draft','post','open','closed','','','','','2019-07-14 12:53:19','0000-00-00 00:00:00',0,0`

at the top of the new post page. I also get a bunch of warnings and notices too, but I figured it's unlikely these are causing the problem:

```
Warning: Creating default object from empty value in wp-admin\includes\post.php on line 475

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$ID in wp-admin\post-new.php on line 64

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$post_date in wp-admin\edit-form-advanced.php on line 49
.
.
.
```

I'm new to php and  WordPress, so does any WP veteran know if these are normal, or do these have to do anything to do with being unable to create new posts or save a new post draft?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this issue by changing all core files inside WordPress since that inside the files can be a malware. This is not a solution for the custom-designed theme because then is probably some mistake inside the theme.

You can download a fresh new install, remove the `wp-content` folder, and `wp-config.php` file and just merge via `FTP/SFTP` to your root folder where is the WordPress install.

I would suggest you create a backup first.

Comment: So you are suggesting WordPress code is corrupt. What do you mean "this is not a solution for the custom-designed theme"? You mean customizations would be discarded if I replace WP's files?

Comment: If it contains malware it can be corrupted. If you've created a custom theme, then the problem can be also inside it.

Comment: Basically I reinstalled WordPress - excluding the database, wp-config.php and whatever was in the wp-content folder - and it looks like we're in good shape now. Thanks.